# ANDROID - Intent to launch app as a file manager

Tags: android, cordova, android-intent, file-manager

I am building an app using `Phonegap` Build. `HTML,CSS,JS`...

**I want the app to come up when the user clicks something that needs a file manager**.

I know, I have to put something in the AndroidManifest, but I have no idea what... Any help?

Another Example: Let's say i am on my home screen (APEX) and want to select a new icon. When I click the icon a list comes up with all the apps I can use to find the icon. These apps include Astro, Box, SolidExplorer, Gallery, and more... How can I get my app to come up on that list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to declare your `activity` in **[manifest](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html)** file with such **[intent-filter](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/intent-filter-element.html)** with specific **[data](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/data-element.html)** elements.

for ex:

```
  <intent-filter> 
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" /> 
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" /> 
    <data android:scheme="file" /> 
    <data android:host="*" /> 
    <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.pdf" /> 
  </intent-filter>
```

Comment: @Pradeep You need to make this comment on the question above cause the OP knows it, I have not used this.

Answer (score 0):

`Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT` may help.

Here is an example of launching a file chooser with image type files.

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
intent.setType("image/*"); // choose any image
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(intent, "File chooser");
startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, REQUEST_CODE);
```

Comment: Hmm. So where do I put this? Is there something I can put in the AndroidManifest to take care of it?

Like I mentioned earlier, I am using Phonegap Build which is HTML/CSS/JS, so I cannot put Java code into it. I can only edit the Manifest.